# Hook on slug generator

Tags: slug

I'd like to change the slug that is automatically generated when creating a post.

[image]

I'd like to add a meta before, making a thing like [meta]-test-slug-2

I guess there's a hook on when WP automatically creates a slug, and if I could find it, I could inject that meta before the title when creating the slug.

So is there a hook that exists? If so, how can I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this using the `wp_unique_post_slug` filter (which is applied in the [function of the same name](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug)):

```
add_filter("wp_unique_post_slug", function($slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug) {
    if($meta = get_post_meta($post_ID, "my-meta", true)) {
        $slug = $meta . '-' . $slug;
    }
    return $slug;
}, 10, 6);
```

As this is applied at the end of that function and I believe WP expects and relies upon that slug to be unique, you will have to make sure that it is. I believe that it will be generated (and saved) as the post is published, so you'll have to have your meta values ready by then.

Comment: I dont know what I'm doing wrong. I'm trying to add the date before as a test, and it doesnt work 
add_filter("wp_unique_post_slug", function($slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug) {
    /*if($meta = get_post_meta($post_ID, "my-meta", true)) {
        $slug = $meta . '-' . $slug;
    }*/
 $slug = date('Y-m-d').'-'.$slug;
    return $slug;
}, 10, 6);

Comment: What's (not) happening? Adding the date that way works fine for me. Is the function not called at all, or is it not saved to the DB (wp_posts => post_name)?

Comment: Threw a priority of 9999, it did pass. My problem was priority.